# Question about a common expression

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I'm not a native speaker, but I found some expression where I couldn't understand the sentence construction.

> #1. Can we get started now?
>
> #2. Let's get started.

Can I change *get* into *be* in the #1, and is the meaning same?
Is it a **pseudo-passive**?

I wonder why people speak like that instead of *Can we start?*
Is there any difference between them?

In #2, Can I understand the usage as above or below?

> We are done talking.

I know it is very common expression, but I can't get the sentence-structure.

Comment: It would be very non-idiomatic (probably, ungrammatical*) to use ***be*** instead of ***get*** in #1. Your example #2 is probably "extra-grammatical". That's to say although it's *idiomatically* well established, it's probably *not* actually "grammatically valid" by any normal standards. I definitely don't think #2 would pass muster in any truly "formal" context.

Comment: I'd say *to be done verbing* is "reduced" from *to be done / finished **with** [the activity of] verbing*. Note that no-one *ever* discards preposition ***with*** in similar constructions like *My boyfriend shouldn't have hit me. I'm done **with** him now.*

Answer (score 1):

This is a "get passive", which is more dynamic than the "be passive".

Compare "get married" (An action you might take on one particular day) with "be married" (A state you might remain in for many years)

Similarly here, you would "get started" as a dynamic action, and no "be started" (which would describe the state)

On the other hand the (somewhat casual) "we are done talking" describes a state, not an action. So the "be passive"  is needed.

In other contexts the get passive and the be passive are sometimes equivalent, but not in these contexts.